# HMS Toolkit Convertor for for RN project

Tags: react-native, toolkit

Do we have any G+H wrapper solution for react native where GMS services and HMS services in the same react native project? Something is similar to HMS toolkit in Android Studio for react native project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no** such G+H wrapper solution for React Native right now and **no** roadmap for this.